# Word counting program in c (it should exclude comments)

Tags: c

I currently got assignment to make word counting program in c. Task is your program should count characters, lines and words. Lines should be counted even if it is inside comment. Comments should be represented as an " " space character.

I tried to use switch function to implement cases inside and outside word. But I am having trouble with comment. In first if statement I tried to check if we are in comment or not and if so skip it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define word 1
#define nword 0

    int main(void)
    {

        int c,d,nmb = 0 , state = nword , ch = 0, ln = 0;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
        {
            if( c == '/' )
            {
                 if((d=getchar())=='*')
                {       

                     int f;
                     c = getchar();
                     d = getchar();

                     while(c!='*' || d !='/')
                     {
                        c = d;
                        d = getchar();
                        if(d == '\n')
                        { ln++ ; ch++; }
                        if(d == EOF)
                        { f=1 ; break; }

                    }
                    if(f==1)
                    printf("problem in line: %d\n", ln);
                    state=word;
                    nmb++;
                }
            }
            switch(state)
            {
                case nword:

                    if(isspace(c))
                     {
                        state=word;
                        nmb++;  
                    }
                    break;
                case word:

                    if(!isspace(c))
                        state=nword;
                    break;
            } 
            if (c == '\n')
            ln++;
            ch++;
        }
        printf("words: %d\n", nmb);
        printf("chars: %d\n", ch);
        printf("lines: %d\n", ln);
        return 0;
    }
```

I cant get right answers to test cases. I cant debug too because I cant see certain pattern which can be fixed. Some test cases matches right but others dont.(Test cases in https://ee209-2019-spring.github.io/assignment/wc209/ )

Comment: You can always debug. Have you tried giving the program a ton of different input yourself and seeing what fails?

Comment: *"I cant debug too because I cant see certain pattern which can be fixed."* - That's definitely not something that makes it impossible to debug.

Comment: When there is no star after a slash, you don't count the slash as character. Also, the speciication says that the input `"abc\n"` is considered two lines, not only one.